# How do I merge pairs based on a nested value?

Tags: merge, clojure

Given the following list in Clojure:

```
(def pairs '[(2,1),(3,2),(2,4)])
```

I want to merge these based overlapping first item in the pair, and select the one with the greater second value.

ie I want them to merge into:

```
[(3,2),(2,4)]
```

because `(2,1)` and `(2,4)` have matching first values, and `(2,4)` has the greater second value, so it bumps off `(2,1)`.

My question is: **How do I merge pairs based on a nested value?**

This is what I attempted:

```
(reduce
  (fn [first-pair second-pair]
    (if (not (= (first first-pair) (first second-pair)))
      (conj first-pair second-pair)
      (if (> (second first-pair) (second second-pair))
        first-pair
        second-pair)))
  pairs
  )
```

Comment: Please add the code with what you have tried already and how it fails so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the simplest is to group all by first and then find max in each group:

```
user> (->> pairs
           (group-by first)
           vals
           (map (fn [data] (apply max-key second data))))
;;=> ((2 4) (3 2))
```

also you can do it in one pass, without intermediate sequences:

```
user> (seq (reduce (fn [acc [f s]]
                     (update acc f (fnil max Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY) s))
                   {} pairs))
;;=> ([2 4] [3 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the intermediate collection, you can group by `first` and the the max for each group.  E.g.

```
user=> (map (partial apply max-key second) (vals (group-by first pairs)))
((2 4) (3 2))
```